how to android document URI to save?
I'd like to save file path uri to SharedPreferences.
fileUri = "/document/document:1000017239"
I dod't load filePath.
Help me. Thanks.
[Save>
Uri fileUri = intent.getData();
...
SharedPreferences pref = Properties.getSharedPreferences(this);
pref.edit().putString(Properties.FILE_PATH, getFilePathDir(fileUri)).apply();
pref.edit().commit();

Load>
  String filePath = pref.getString(Properties.FILE_PATH, "");


Could you please to share your stacktrace? It is not clear what is your error is.

There is no "file path", as the document does not have to be a file. You can persist the Uri itself, so long as you use takePersistableUriPermissions().

Thanks. Comment. I write a stack trace after today. I don't understand Android Uri because window application developer. I tried to use  takePersistableUriPermissions().
